# Why does the @bazel/protractor npm package still exist when Protractor is deprecated?

Tags: angular, angular-material, bazel-rules

Just wondering as to the purpose of this line in the package.json build file of the Angular Material codebase.
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/cb296970909fbec28470eeb64f162e26e2b6735b/package.json#L93
I thought Protractor was deprecated a while back - see the orange bar on the top of the [Protractor website](https://www.protractortest.org/#/).

Or, why is the Angular Material project using Protractor at all? :)

If there's a use case for Protractor via Bazel, it would be advantageous to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the [link](https://blog.angular.io/the-state-of-end-to-end-testing-with-angular-d175f751cb9c) in the very bar that you mentioned in your question, you will find the answer there.

> As of v12 Protractor is no longer included as part of new Angular CLI
> applications. Starting today we’ll only publish critical bug fixes and
> follow Angular’s deprecation practices. In Angular v16, which is
> expected in the summer of 2023, we’ll publish the last release of
> Protractor.

This means that while it won't avaialbe as an option during generation of new projects using CLI, it will still be supported so that people who can't (or don't want to) migrate to other e2e are not left on ice. It's mostly for backwards comptability.

In addition, in the same link, they mention that while protractor project reached end of it's life, they will support public branch that will still be developed by external dev team.

Comment: Thanks for this.

My question wasn't about why regular users shouldn't use Protractor.

My question was about why Angular Material devs are *still* using Protractor knowing full well that it's going away. 

Why do they continue to write tests in Protractor rather than use another testing framework? Is it a reason that is specific to the Angular Material codebase or is there an advantage to them that can also be an advantage to regular users, despite the deprecation notice?

Comment: For example the Angular project devs vendor Yarn and apply patches. For regular users this doesn't make sense. But for the Angular infrastructure project, they do it so that yarn and bazel can work with renovate. See https://github.com/angular/dev-infra/commit/06d2e615d9f6a541005695b62e6e312a355bbd39 So it's only specific to the Angular project, it makes no sense for regular users. The latter shouldn't vendor yarn or apply the patch approach above, it is counterproductive. It only makes sense to Angular project devs. Sorry for the repetition but I want to make my question clear. Thanks!